# вывести pdf фалй полученный по curl

Tags: php, curl

как вывести на страницу pdf файл полученный по `curl` через обращение на api ?
если вывести `print_r` `result` То ничего нет , как убедится что файл получен ?

Comment: [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php)

Comment: @Эдуард пусто , ничего нет, может можно проверить что вернул curl есть ли ошибки точнее

Comment: Проверяйте значение переменной $result _(если именно в эту переменную вы получаете результат работы curl)_: `var_dump($result);` **UPD:** [curl_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: @Эдуард вообще curl возвращает текущую страницу на которой исполняется код если оформить его заголовками 

`header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
echo($result);`